# MySQL Stored Procedure using IN variable name not value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure defined:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Create_Domain_Table`;
DELIMITER ;;
PROCEDURE `Create_Domain_Table`(IN newTable VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
       CREATE TABLE newTable LIKE `domain_template`;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

However when I call the procedure e.g.

```
CALL Create_Domain_Table('test_domain_table');
```

it creates a new table with the a name of newtable and not test_domain_table.

Is there something wrong with my syntax or am I referencing the parameter incorrectly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *Dynamic SQL* on this,

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Create_Domain_Table`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `Create_Domain_Table`(IN newTable VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

   SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `', newTable,'` LIKE domain_template');

   PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
   EXECUTE stmt;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. Unfortunately I get the following error: [ERROR in query 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PROCEDURE 'Create_Domain_Table' (IN newTable varchar(255))
BEGIN
SET @sql = CONCAT' at line 1

Comment: sorry, i copy-paste your statement provided. It should be `CREATE PROCEDURE` not `PROCEDURE`.